# How to iterate through a JavaFX-combobox?

Tags: java, combobox, foreach, iterator, javafx

My question is simple: How do I iterate throught a javafx-combobox? I tried so much and nothing works. The foreach-construct does not work and combobox does not even have methods for size and single object retrieval, eliminating the possibility to use a simple-for-loop. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are missing..or maybe not. But, nevertheless, just return `ObservableList` of objects from your `ComboBox` and use for each to iterate through that collection. Here is an example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxExample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        Button button = new Button("Print items from ComboBox");
        final ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
        //Add some items
        comboBox.getItems().addAll("John","Jane","Laina");

        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                //To iterate through ComboBox
                ObservableList<String> items = comboBox.getItems();
                for(String item : items){
                    System.out.println(item.toString());
                }
            }
        });

        gridPane.add(comboBox,0,0);
        gridPane.add(button,0,1);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(gridPane,320,280));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, you are declaring a ObservableList<String>... Thank you. But I wonder why this works: I tried `for(String item: comboBox.getItems()` and javac complained. Actually your code does the same, apart from the fact that you are declaring the ObservableList to contain strings. Strange...

Comment: Probably because you didn't specify data type for items in your `ComboBox`. This: `ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<String>();`

Comment: Yeah, that cuts it. Thank you.